# Puma Logging Differently In Production vs Development Environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma, puma-dev

Puma is logging differently when running the server in a production environment versus a development environment. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: In what way is it different? The log level can be (usually is) set per environment (`config/environments/*rb`), but if you mean something other than that you need to be more specific.

Comment: They're different for your own server's sake. Development env shows verbose information for dev activity such as Query, Route's insight, Views and Partials loaded, etc. While in prod, you really do not care which partial was loaded when. This saves you from ending up with a huge log file on production which has less meaningful data for debugging.

I recommend you look at you config/environment/development.rb and production.rb files for those differences.

Answer (score 0):

did you check `production.rb`?
you can open production.rb and then found `config.log_level = :info`

you can change value of `:info` to `:debug` if you want do that.

but when you coding on development environment, must need `:debug` in development.rb because you finding some bug or something wrong.
computer was not lie, log is good evidence for investgatation bug.

**why log level is `:info` in production environment.**
if you set debug to log level, your production system will face error `No space left on device`  and then many system need high level than `:debug` level.

`:info` level is higher than `:debug`.
this mean that `:info` generate log less than `:debug`, and generate short log.